# Link svg paths from external file to be displayed in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a bunch of svg paths (for icons) which work fine if they are placed directly in the html. But with so many, I want to put them into an external file instead. I cant use `object` or `img` as I am using css to style them. any ideas?

```
<!-- svg paths -->
<symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" id="icon1">
  <path d="..."></path>
</symbol>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" id="icon2">
  <path d="..."></path>
</symbol>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" id="icon3">
  <path d="..."></path>
</symbol>
```

```
<!-- html -->
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#icon1"></use>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#icon2"></use>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#icon3"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: you can use SVG as background image

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filename in front of the id reference. Like here I'm referring to the symbol `s2` in the file `symbols.svg`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG symbol</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <use href="symbols.svg#s2" />
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```