# Linking external file with svg tags to HTML

Tags: html, flask, svg

I'm trying to create an external file having the SVG icons in below format

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="icon1" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cloud-download-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0a5.53 5.53 0 0 0-3.594 1.342c-.766.66-1.321 1.52-1.464 2.383C1.266 4.095 0 5.555 0 7.318 0 9.366 1.708 11 3.781 11H7.5V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V11h4.188C14.502 11 16 9.57 16 7.773c0-1.636-1.242-2.969-2.834-3.194C12.923 1.999 10.69 0 8 0zm-.354 15.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 14.293V11h-1v3.293l-2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="icon2" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cloud-download-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M4.406 1.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 0c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 4.804 16 6.137 16 7.773 16 9.569 14.502 11 12.687 11H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2.688C13.979 10 15 8.988 15 7.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 2.825 10.328 1 8 1a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1c-.757.652-1.153 1.438-1.153 2.055v.448l-.445.049C2.064 4.805 1 5.952 1 7.318 1 8.785 2.23 10 3.781 10H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3.781C1.708 11 0 9.366 0 7.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383z"/>
    <path d="M7.646 15.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 14.293V5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793l-2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

And is there a way possible to link the above file to the HTML so that I can use the icon with below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg>
        <use href="demo.svg#icon2" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I creating a flask web app for a practice where I only need 5-6 icons. Currently, I'm using inline SVG which is working fine but it makes the code very large and I'm looking for a way to refactor the code.

Comment: This is the same question as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69265973/link-svg-paths-from-external-file-to-be-displayed-in-html

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="icon1" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cloud-download-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0a5.53 5.53 0 0 0-3.594 1.342c-.766.66-1.321 1.52-1.464 2.383C1.266 4.095 0 5.555 0 7.318 0 9.366 1.708 11 3.781 11H7.5V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V11h4.188C14.502 11 16 9.57 16 7.773c0-1.636-1.242-2.969-2.834-3.194C12.923 1.999 10.69 0 8 0zm-.354 15.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 14.293V11h-1v3.293l-2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="icon2" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cloud-download-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M4.406 1.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 0c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 4.804 16 6.137 16 7.773 16 9.569 14.502 11 12.687 11H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2.688C13.979 10 15 8.988 15 7.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 2.825 10.328 1 8 1a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1c-.757.652-1.153 1.438-1.153 2.055v.448l-.445.049C2.064 4.805 1 5.952 1 7.318 1 8.785 2.23 10 3.781 10H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3.781C1.708 11 0 9.366 0 7.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383z"/>
    <path d="M7.646 15.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 14.293V5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793l-2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

  <div>
    <svg class="icon icon-heart"><use xlink:href="#icon1"></use></svg>

    <svg class="icon icon-cloud"><use xlink:href="#icon2"></use></svg>
  </div>
```

You can use SVG Sprites to refer to.

You would have one SVG-File like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

<symbol id="icon1" viewBox="0 0 34 73">
    // Your SVG paths and so on
</symbol>

<symbol id="icon2" viewBox="0 0 34 73">
    // Your SVG paths and so on
</symbol>
```

and you use the single icons from that file like this in your html:

```
<svg class="your-class-to-style">
    <use xlink:href="{svg-path}/#icon1"></use>
</svg>

<svg class="your-class-to-style">
    <use xlink:href="{svg-path}/#icon2"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: It is not working

Comment: The path should be "{svg-path}#icon2" without the "/". So for example: "file.svg#icon2"

Comment: the path should be absolute or relative?

Comment: I have updated the question with my code, can you please check why it is not working

Comment: Use 'xlink:href' instead of 'href'

Comment: @AshisSahoo I edited my answer with an example with the svg inside the html you can run. When the svg file is external stored you have to change the path of course.